# How to scope providers on several widgets without putting the provider on a root widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-navigation

I'm working on a simple demo where the user logs in, sees a list of items, clicks on an item, and then sees its details. These are 3 screens but let's say two flows where one deals with login and the other with items.

I'm managing my state using `provider` package. I placed a `LoginRepository` provider on my root widget because that state is needed everywhere. This works great.

Now I need an `ItemRepository` which should be available on the `ItemListScreen` and the `ItemDetailScreen`. To implement that scoping, I decided to create a common ancestor widget called `ItemScreens`. This is where I placed my provider and my **nested** `Navigator`.

I navigate my screens using `Navigator.of(context)` to make sure the closes ancestor navigator is used. I fetch my provider using `Provider.of<ItemRepository>(context)` to make sure the closes ancestor state is used.

This apparently does not work because I get a `Could not find the correct provider`. I understand that the provider from the sibling route cannot be accessed by another sibling but here I'm nesting navigators I would expect the `ItemRepository` to be placed at `ItemScreens` which then handles subrouting so that these two routes can fetch providers from the parent route?

**Sidenote:**
Flutter [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple) clearly states that providers should be lifted to achieve proper scoping. But I've never seen an example where the provider was lifted to a non-root widget. If all we can do is place providers into the root widget, that should be clearly stated.

EDIT: Re-creating providers on several widgets is kind of an alternative but that's not really scoping it's just pseudo passing by value.

EDIT: Putting all providers on the root widget with `MultiProvider` isn't a good idea because it creates a global state anti-pattern. Some states should also simply not be created unless needed i.e. the user is visiting that flow/screen.

Comment: Have you found a good solution to this problem? Currently I'm using GetIt + Provider to achieve scoping but this solution feels fragile.

Comment: No, this question came up during a hackathon. I didn't revisit the topic since then.

Comment: aparently there's no good way to do this in Provider and was one of the main reasons for Riverpod.  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/30062#issuecomment-1163290913

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your MaterialApp Widget in main.dart with Multiprovider and give the list of providers you are using, That way App knows which class to treat as providers.

```js
MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => FirstProvider(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(
            create: (_) => SecondProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Auro',
          home: _decideMainPage(context),
          // routes: routes,
          theme: AllCoustomTheme.getThemeData(),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Hi, Abhinav welcome to the community and thanks for the answer. I'd like to avoid placing all of my states on the root widget because that would be a global state which isn't desirable. I also wouldn't want to create `ItemRepository` unless I was logged in. For instance, the `ItemRepository` constructor may need an authentication header before it is created.